# Ramdisk mounted at mnt/ramdisk goes to /run/user

Tags: linux, files, ramdisk

To create a ramdisk (Ubuntu 18.04), I issued "sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk" at the Putty terminal prompt.  Then I issued "mount | tail -n 1" and it returned:

```
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs  (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=100912k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Now to unmount I issued "sudo umount /mnt/ramdisk/" but it said not found. So instead I issued "sudo umount /run/user/1000/" (part of the return from the mount command).  Then, to be sure it's gone, I issued "mount | tail -n 1" and it returned:

```
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type  tmpfs(rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=100912k,mode=700)
```

So I issued "sudo umount /run/user/0/"

Finally it's gone.

My questions are:

1. When I mount a ramdisk at /mnt/ramdisk, how do I know where the ramdisk will actually be mounted so I can unmount it?  This was done at the Linux command line, but if I did it with system() in a C program, how can I get the actual mount point to unmount it?
2. When I unmounted /run/user/1000/ why did it end up at /run/user/0/?
3. Why didn't it just go to /mnt/ramdisk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ramdisk created by the system at `/run/user/1000` is for system processes and I would create a new, dedicated one if you wish to use it for your own purposes.

`sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk` will create a folder called `ramdisk` in the folder `/mnt` but not a ram disk.

If you wish to mount a RAM disk to the `/mnt/ramdisk` folder, usable by the user you log in as, enter the following (**one time use**):

```
mount -o size=4G,uid=1000 -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

(replace "4G" with the required size)

If it should be created **at each boot**, edit `/etc/fstab` as root (e.g. by `sudo nano /etc/fstab`) and add a line like this

```
none /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs size=4G,uid=1000 0 0
```

Then during each boot a new, empty ram disk will be mounted at `/mnt/ramdisk` for files discarded during shutdown.

Comment: Should I assume it will be found at /run/user/1000?  Or does that vary?

Comment: No, I will add more info.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  Where does "uid-1000" come from?

Comment: Each Linux user has a numerical ID as well as a user name. Perhaps you log in as "john" but internally there is a number behind it. I use numerical IDs here because I do not know your username but could derive your ID from your question. The first Linux user (person) normally has the user ID (UID) 1000.